# Minor flaw in understanding of the proof of the derivative of exponential functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function, proof-explanation

I understand the majority of the proof of the derivative formula for exponential functions of the form: (full proof at bottom of post)

$\frac{d}{dx}a^x$

but I have a little trouble with the last step which implies that the rate of change of any exponential function if proportional to both the function itself *and the derivative of the function at zero.* I fail to see how

$\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{a^h-1}{h}}=f'(0)$

*the limit is supposedly the value of the derivative of $a^x$ at $0$, but to me the limit seems only to be a simplified part of the whole definition of the derivative of the function! Where is the flaw in this line of reasoning?

(to clarify my question: It seems like the $lim_{h\to 0}$ defines the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ anywhere, not just $0$.)

Proof:

$f(x)=a^x$

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}$

$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{a^{x+h} -a^x}{h}}$

$=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{a^x(a^h-1)}{h}}$

$=a^x \cdot \lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{a^h-1}{h}}$
, and supposedly $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{a^h-1}{h}}$, so

$f'(x)=f'(0)\cdot a^x$

$\square$

I also apologize to anyone who finds this question too basic; I just can't seem to break this mental block. Any help from a deeper understanding is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h}.$$ What is the quotient on the right?

Comment: You have said $\displaystyle f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{a^{x+h} -a^x}{h}}$, so letting $x=0$ gives $\displaystyle f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}{\dfrac{a^{h} -a^0}{h}}$, and $a^0=1$

Comment: *"...but to me the limit seems only to be a simplified part of the whole definition of the derivative of the function!"*  Your sentence says "supposedly A, but B" where both A and B are correct.  There is no tension between the two or as to the validity of either one on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent of the proof is to relate the derivative at $x$ to the derivative at $0$, which is possible thanks to the property $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$.

It states

$$f'(x)=(a^x)'=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}h=\lim_{h\to0}a^x\frac{a^{h}-1}h=a^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^{h}-1}h=a^xL_a.$$

And obviously, setting $x=0$, you have $f'(0)=(a^x)'|_{x=0}=a^0L_a=L_a$.

This is a major finding, as you can compute the derivative via a constant,

$$f'(x)=(a^x)'=a^xL_a=a^xf'(0).$$

Of course, this doesn't say what $L_a$ is (not even if it exists), but what matters at this stage is that there is no dependency on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $$f'(t) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(t+h) - f(t)}{h}.$$  For $a > 0$ and $f(t) = a^t$, we get $$f'(t) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^{t+h} - a^t}{h}.$$  Now let $t = 0$:  $$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^{0+h} - a^0}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h - 1}{h}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The limit is the same as the one that defines $f'(0)$ using the definition of derivative applied to this function $f$.   The harder part of the proof, not written in the question, is to show that this limit exists and to determine its value (a logarithm) as a function of the base $a$.  The calculation posted in the question is the easier algebraic step of proving $f'(x) = f(x) f'(0)$.